# How to find out if cookie expired in Flask app

Tags: cookies, flask

I'm using session expiration in Flask. Ideally I would like to flash appropriate message after session expires and redirect to login page. It seems like there is no way to get expiry information from the cookie to test for that or am I missing something?

Comment: Browsers pass cookies as key-value pairs. When a cookie has expired, the browser doesn't send it.

Answer (score 1):

If the session has expired, the session cookie is no longer present in the browser.

[From the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#sessions), `session` is a python dictionary.

> The session object works pretty much like an ordinary dict...

For, example, You set the session by: `session['username'] = 'xxxxxx'`.

To check if that cookie is still available, use `session.get('username')`. If it returns `None`, the cookie is absent, else, the cookie is present.

The check becomes:

```
if not session.get('user'):
    flash('Not so fast! Kindly login to view that page')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
else:
    #...Do something with logged-in user
```

[Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) are two extensions that handle user login and sessions very well for you.