# A way to detect session expiration in flask?

Tags: flask, flask-session

In Flask I want to delete some files when the session times out. I don't have user-login - anyone can upload images and do stuff with them. I want the images to disappear when the session does. But how do I detect when that is?

I believe it will not make sense to store the images in RAM, that's why I want to save them on the server and remove them again.

edit: code for view function and html for rendering PDF with images that are to be deleted when session times out.

views.py:

```
from flask import (render_template, request)
from flask_weasyprint import HTML, render_pdf


from .forms import toPDF
from .helpers import (custom_images_in_collection)



@user_blueprint.route("/collection", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def collection():

    form = toPDF()

    # 'collection' is a list of preexisting/permanent image objects selected by user and stored in session
    # custom_images is a list of extra image objects created by user on the fly. They're stored
    # and retreived from the database from their own table of temporary images with a time field.
    # I want the custom images to disappear when the session expires
    custom_images = custom_images_in_collection(collection)
    collection.append(custom_images)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if collection:
            if form.validate_on_submit():

                template = render_template("mypdf.html", collection=collection)
                html = HTML(string=template)
                # This bit of CSS is dynamically generated, the rest is hard coded in the template

                return render_pdf(html)

    return render_template("collection.html", collection=collection, form=form)
```

mypdf.html:

```
{% if collection|length %}
<div class="innerbox">
    {% for word in collection %}
    <div class="imgcard">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + word.image.name)}}"
                alt="image of '{{ word.word }}'">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">{{ word.word }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}

{% else %}
<div class="col-4">
    <p>You don't have a collection yet!</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: For checking if the session has expired see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36496036/9098350). Basically if it's expired it will be `None` if you try to retrieve it. You could also just read in the image data do something with it and not store it in the first place. This could be an xy problem. Do you want to remove the images after the session is expired because you don't want to store them anyway or do you really want to remove them only when the session is expired?

Comment: It's an app where the user can upload and crop up to 20 images and choose one of my templates for displaying them. Then they'll have a PDF generated. For this I'm using WeazyPrint and I don't know how I could do it without having the images stored. So I'd like to store them under a unique id for this session and to make sure the images do get deleted, check when the session containing this specific ID doesn't exist anymore and delete them then. In the post you refer to I think the actual session still needs to be active to check if a variable inside it exists.

Comment: Can you share the code which uploads the images and generates the pdf? I haven't used WeazyPrint before but from looking at the [api](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) I see a couple functions with a `target` parameter that can point to a file location, but can also be passed a file object to. So you might be able to pass the file object when a user selects a file to upload without saving it somewhere. I think the session approach is more difficult.

Comment: Sure! Sorry, this took some time because I went on a road trip and then had to edit out all the irrelevant bits of code.